# Create a function inside a function into a class?

Tags: php

I'm trying to create some classes and i would like to use this syntax:

```
$my = new My();
$my->field()->test('test');
```

I know how to do a `$my->test('test')`, it's easy - but I don't know how to add a `field()` attribute to make an easier comprehension of my class in my code.

I can guess it's something like a class into another class - extends - but i'm not sure about that so if you know how to do something similar.

I precise it's only for a better comprehension into my class. I mean the aim is to categorize functions in this `My` class.

Thank you :)

Comment: What is the *concrete* problem you run into? Just ask about it, because I must admit I have problems to decipher it from your question. And why are you not *able* to do so? To *which* language feature / object feature do you related to here? If one function works, why are you not able to understand that the other function is the same language concept? Or if you understand that, where do you hit the road-block?

Answer (score 2):

If you break your php down a bit, you will understand what is going on. For example lets make this:

```
$my->field()->test('test');
```

into this (for clarification).

```
$newObject = $my->field();
$newObject->test('test');
```

From here you can observe that the return of the method $my->field() is actually an object with another method test which you can then call. It is called method chaining and can be useful at times.

Here is a test case:

```
class a{
    public function My(){
        return new b;
    }
}

class b{
    public function foo(){
        echo 'hello bar';
    }
}

$a = new a();
$a->My()->foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to carry out an action on a method the method needs to return an object.

```
class a {
   public function b($c){
       echo $c;
       return $this;
   }
 }
```

would allow

```
$d = new a();
$d->b("foo")->b("bar");
$d->b("foo")->b("bar")->b("far")->b("tar");
```